# Sampling from two dependent variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, sampling

Suppose: I have two variables (T and E), that in turn depend on two other variables (p,q) as follows:

$T(p,q) = \frac{1-p^{2}}{1-q^{2}}$
and 
$E(q) = 1-q$

$q$ and $p$ are both limited to the interval $0$ and $1$.

Now, both $T$ and $E$ are assumed to be Gaussian distributed, with $\mu_{T},\sigma_{T}$ and $\mu_{E},\sigma_{E}$. These parameters are known. $\sigma$'s will in general be small such that the limits on $q$ and $p$ don't affect the Gaussian assumption on $T$ and $E$ much.

Ultimately, I want to sample $p$ and $q$. How do I do that with the information above, the complexity being that as soon as sample from the Gaussian of $E$, a value of $q$ is achieved which alters the distribution for $T$?

Comment: Are $T$ and $Q$ assumed to be independent? Any constraint on $p$ or $q$? (Note that the sign of $p$ is arbitrary.)

Comment: Sorry, yes those are things I should have added. 
Do you mean $T$ and $E$? The paper is not very explicit on it, but I think they are to be taken to be independent. 
$p$ and $q$ both have a constraint to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, I meant $E$, not $Q$. If both $p$ and $q$ are on $(0,1)$, neither $E=1-q$  nor $T=(1-p^2)/(1-q^2)$can be a Gaussian.

Comment: With sufficiently small $\sigma$, approximately Gaussian. Astronomers have no problems here ;-)

Comment: If you are fine with these approximations, simulate $T$ and $E$ independently and solve both equations, $E$ first in $q$ and $T$ second in $p$. But I would suggest deleting this question.

Comment: Are the four parameters of the two normals known?

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect the actual situation (including small $\sigma$'s,  approximate normality and your belief about the independence -- along with expanding why you think so); an explicit reference to the paper may help.

Comment: @Xi'an  The T-variable is in general not independent of the E-variable, since they are both a function of $q$. This is exactly the difficutly the OP faces.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: I do not understand the arguments. Let us takes $T$ and $E$ as independent $N(0,1)$ variates and then define e.g. $T=p/1-q$ and $E=q$. This does not make $T$ and $E$ dependent, but $q$ and $p$ dependent.

Comment: @Alecos Xi'an is correct: simply generate $(T,E)$ independently with the specified parameters and set $$(q,p)=\left(1-E,\sqrt{1-2ET+E^2T}\right).$$Throw away (but monitor the occurrences of) any values of $(q,p)$ outside $[0,1]^2$--the hope is that none will appear.

Comment: @whuber I was trying to take clues from the verbal description of the OP and to understand why the OP faces a problem. The OP writes "I have two variables which _in turn_depend on...". I am not a native English speaker but I think this syntax, although vague, indicates that the "underlying / generating rv's" are $p$ and $q$, not $T$ and $E$. Also, if we start by $T$ and $E$ independent, then the steps are obvious and present no problem - and I guess I thought "If this was the case, if E and T were the "primary" variables, the OP would have understood how to generate p and q, being so obvious".